# How do I get rid of errors for disconnected networked drives?

Tags: macos, network, hard-drive

Every time I log into OSX 10.9.4 (and several slightly older versions since I've been updating) I get several pop-ups asking me to connect to a remote/networked drive that I've previously configured, yet deleted:

```
Enter your name and password for the server "my_remote_server".
```

..followed by the error about connecting, but that's fine because the drives have been deleted on the server side, so there should be no way to actually connect.

There is a pair of pop-ups per drive/server (each drive has its own server, and I configured several drives). I also get a similar message when opening my Chrome browser.

I removed these drives (using Finder->Go->Connect to Server) and the problem is still there. I've also checked `/etc/fstab`, `/Volumes`, and used the `df` command although that's pretty much the same as checking fstab.

It appears that the drives are completely disconnected/unmounted, so the problem is that I'm still getting the error pop-ups. I tried this but it didn't work: http://whatsamknows.tumblr.com/post/37368603810/get-rid-of-server-connections-interrupted

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you using LDAP?

Comment: I'm really not sure, how do I find out? I did all of this stuff a long time ago and I'm finally coming back around to fix it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's every time you log in, it could be in your login items. Check System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items for links to those volumes.

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted. have +1 on me

Comment: Under 'Login Items' there were some rows with my directory, and they each had a little yellow warning symbol next to them. Deleting these rows fixed the problem